# I do not understand what going on recently in site

Tags: discussion

I do not understand what going on recently in site.

I suppose that site is to help people.

I do not understand why people close questions.

If you will continue to close questions people will go to other places.

https://serverfault.com/questions/744213/how-to-configure-freeradius-to-support-two-factor-auth

**Added**

Dear EEEA, I was required only to put the link that point to tutorial. 
Sometime just put the link in the answers help a lot!!!
Thank for one kind person that did it!!!

It will help me and for future people.

So, what is more important to you: to help to people or to follow rules that were added recently?

You wrong about the assumption that I give up.

Comment: This is a question and answer site. Not Thinking As A Service, Free Consulting As A Service, Remote Diagnosis as a service. Ask a question get an answer. You have to put some effort in an not expect us to hold your hand through a process to get a personalised answer.

Comment: Links to tutorials without some form of precis in the answer are to be avoided as links can go dead. I read the link in the comment. It's not reasonably practical to precis that because it is too long and technical so it would not make a good answer. The community did a good job of closing a very poor question. I also read the link that you eventually provided to prove you had tried. That just told me that you didn't really have a grasp of what you were trying to do and I should avoid you.

Comment: Nothing has changed in this community. We have always had a low tolerance for poor questions. Please learn from that.

Answer (score 14):

> I do not understand what going on recently in site.

Questions and answers, the same as always. Some great great questions, some bad questions. Great questions get great answers, bad questions either get closed or get bad answers. Status quo, more or less.

> I suppose that site is to help people.

Yep, for sure, but we don't do handouts. We expect people to provide ample details on the problem for us to understand it, and to provide ample information about what you've tried, what worked, what didn't work, etc.

> I do not understand why people close questions.

Questions get put on hold for a variety of reasons. The reason why yours was put on hold is stated clearly in the block below your question.

Keep in mind - your question has not been closed. It's been put on hold. This is a warning of sorts from the community to you, to communicate that your question needs improvement before it'll be answered. If you improve your question, it will be considered for re-opening.

As stated above, provide details on what you've done. Pointing us to a tutorial and saying "HALP, IT DIDN'T WORK!!!!!111" isn't helping us to help you. Details, details, details. We need logs, configuration files, etc. Michael Hampton has already given you [specific ways](https://serverfault.com/questions/744213/how-to-configure-freeradius-to-support-two-factor-auth#comment931725_744213) in which you could improve your question, but you are apparently ignoring that request, so I'm not sure what you expect us to do.

It is also worth noting that we don't do tutorials. There are plenty of tutorials elsewhere on the internet, and Stack Exchange sites are not meant to be repositories of tutorials.

> If you will continue to close questions people will go to other
>   places.

Off-topic and other sub-standard questions will continue to be closed. Closing questions is a way in which we can enforce community standards and encourage people to put ample effort into their questions.

Comment: Dear EEEA, I was required only to add the link that point to tutorial. 
Sometime just put the link in the answers help a lot!!!

It will help me and for future people,

So, what is more important to you: to help to people or to follow rules that were added recently?

You wrong about the assumption that I give up.

Comment: @Michael Link-only answers are all but worthless here, and as mentioned previously, we don't do tutorials. To be completely honest, tutorials are a very dangerous thing to rely on, as following them encourages copy/paste sysadmin practices, and doesn't encourage you to actually **learn** the technologies in use. Also, to be clear, I never said anything about you giving up.

Answer (score 6):

> So, what is more important to you: to help to people or to follow rules that were added recently?

It's not a situation where you need to pick between the two. The goal is always to help people by answering their questions, and the rules are there to make that happen more smoothly. You don't have a specific answerable question, you need a guide. That's something you can't expect from a Q&A website.